# All media stopped playing

Tags: multimedia

Something definitely went wrong somewhere along the way.

I had several videos in Windows video/audio format.  Suddenly, none of
them play correctly.

The audio plays OK, but the video display is frozen on frame one.

I have tried Windows Media Player, Real Player, ZLC Media player, all
with the same results.

System has been rebooted several times.

I can watch YouTube videos OK. Audio only .mp3 audio files play ok.
Embedded videos on news web sites and things like Comedy Central
play fine also.

These are foreign music videos that I have saved to my HDD to remind me of the
time I spent overseas while in the USAF. Most are Korean and Vietnamese traditional
folk songs.

System is Win7-32 Ultimate. All updated to most recent versions. The only recent change made to the
systems was to uninstall Avast free antivirus, and install the newly released Zone Alarm free Firewall/Antivirus combo package. I had been using ZA Free Firewall & Avast Free AV.

H E L P  !!!  I miss my music video files.

Where do I start to troubleshoot?  If it was unique to one player I could understand it, but this is across the board.  The player application opens, and video is fixed on the first frame, while audio plays normally.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's local media only, but not application-specific, then for the 'next step' try checking the Windows Event Log for disk errors, and run disk checks (ie: `chkdsk c:`) to ensure your hard disks and file system are healthy.